# Make Amazon Echo talk by sending a request to it

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I know this was, apparently, not possible before. It has been over half a year since this was answered with a vaguely "no".

Is it possible to trigger Alexa to say something? I basically want her to receive a request from my server (home or remote), then say what I just sent her in that request.

Comment: If you want to get some more attention for the existing question (e.g. to check if it's outdated), you can leave a comment or place a bounty on the existing question with the "current answers outdated" reason. However, I think little has changed since the question was posted (6 months isn't a huge length of time). Hope this helps.